# How to add a single column php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to add a single column in a db query result. I've read about the SUM(col_name) as TOTAL, GROUP BY (col_name2).
But is there a way i can only SUM the column without any GROUPing? I a case whereby all col_name2 are all unique.

For example... I have a result  with the following col headers:

course_code

course_title

course_unit

score

grade

Assuming this have 12 rows returned into an HTML table. Now i want to perform SUM() on all the values (12 rows) for the column course_unit, in other to implement a GPA school grading system.

How can i achieve this.

Thanks.

Comment: if you read a little more, you will find that you can use sum without groupby to have a sum of all retrieved rows ;)

Comment: @dotunoyesanmi: Please see the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As comments below have already pointed out: `SELECT SUM(course_unit) AS total FROM your_table;`. Note that this is a separate query to the one with which you retrieve the table data.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT SUM(col_name) as 'total' FROM <table>
```

`GROUP BY` is required only if you want to sum subsets of the rows in the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can find sum or any aggregate db functions (such as `count`, `avg`, etc) for most cases without using group clause. Your sql query may look something like this:

`SELECT SUM(course_unit) as "Total" FROM <table_name>;`

Answer (score 0):

This does it in php.  I'm not sure how to do it with pure sql

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$sum = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sum+= intval($row['course_unit']);
}

echo $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
course_code, 
course_title, 
course_unit, 
score, grade, 
(select sum(course_unit) from TableA) total
from TableA;
```